# How can I deploy a solution to a farm with 2 WFE?

Tags: deployment, solution-deployment

How should I deploy my solution to a farm with 2 WFE?
Should I deploy to the WFE one by one or what's the procedures? How should I configure my solution in visual studio?

I tried to deploy it direct on the server, but it just stucks in "Deploying" status in SharePoint 2010, Please point me the right direction!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Deploying to 2 web front ends is likely not the issue, SharePoint handles this automatically.  Start troubleshooting other aspects of the deployment (is the Timer Service "Stuck", if this is a custom solution, start debugging and reviewing code, etc.)

Comment: A suggestion actually, close this question, and open another question about the specific problem you are having (show log files, etc.) maybe this can give us a better idea.

Answer (score 2):

Deploying a wsp on a farm requires the same steps irrespective of the number of WFE servers configured in the farm.

In a farm based environment, it is recommended to deploy a WSP via powershell instead of hooking Visual Studio to a WFE server and running a deployment.

Visual Studio based deployment should only be done in development systems.

If the status of a wsp deployment is stuck on starting , try to restart the timer service (owstimer.exe) and verify the ULS logs for detailed description and analysis for the root cause.